# robots.txt block all except lighthouse

Tags: seo, robots.txt, lighthouse

I have a staging site, that I want to be able to test via google lighthouse - but do not want google to index it.

When I use this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Lighthouse and google are blocked.

I think the user-agent is "Chrome-Lighthouse" for lighthouse ([source](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/google-lighthouse/)), but I'm not sure how to write the syntax for robot.txt.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure this is on-topic here.  You might also ask on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com.  See: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think the user-agent is "Chrome-Lighthouse" for lighthouse, but I'm not sure how to write the syntax for robot.txt

Comment: OK, then maybe see [Disallow all for all user agents except one user agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33617859).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you dbc the link gave me the answer

```
useragent: *
disallow= /

useragent: Chrome-Lighthouse
allow= /
```

Based on the comment it should be:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Chrome-Lighthouse
Allow: /
```

Comment: This is not correct. It’s `User-agent` and `Disallow:` / `Allow:`.

Comment: Thank you - so lighthouse ignored it because it was malformed

Comment: The robots.txt you included in your question is syntactically correct. The corrected syntax in your answer is still incorrect. I’ll edit it.