# App Search API Validation Tool displays "example.com is returning 469. Please check your url and try again."

Tags: ios-universal-links

I am online a fresh webpage for the purpose of universal links. I put the file in .well-known folder.

In the server log I can see that Applebot got 200 on "GET /.well-known/apple-app-site-association HTTP/1.1"

The only error displayed in the App Search API Validation Tool is:
"example.com is returning 469. Please check your url and try again."

I used another tool to check it - [branch.io AASA Validator](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) and it displays no errors.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure you don't have any robots.txt file in the root that disables Applebot

[Robots.txt: allow only major SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671491/robots-txt-allow-only-major-se)

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204683

Answer (score 2):

Looks like apple changed the format of AASA file. According to [this official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains), the old presentation

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "{PREFIX}.{BUNDLE_ID}",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Had already changed to:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "{PREFIX}.{BUNDLE_ID}"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Considering backward compatibility, you can try writing in this format:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "{PREFIX}.{BUNDLE_ID}",
                "paths": ["*"],
                "appIDs": [
                    "{PREFIX}.{BUNDLE_ID}"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This works for me, hope it helps.

Comment: Is the second way that you have put also valid? I have to bundleIds for my app (one for the store and the other for the devs), so I think that I can write "appIDs": [
                    "{PREFIX1}.{BUNDLE_ID1}",  "{PREFIX2}.{BUNDLE_ID2}"
                ]

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was adding image metadata on top of title and description metadata. I also added Touch icons, but I do not think it caused the issue since it works fine on another website I have without it.

Required metadata seems to be: Title, description and Image (og:image was the missing one in my case)

For metadata check out: [The Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/)

For icons check out: [Developer Apple - Configuring Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW4)