# iOS Universal links apple-app-site-association file issue

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to set up universal links for my app. I've placed apple-app-site-association file in .well-known directory of web server. Url to it allow me download this file. But I have error when use https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/: " 'myurl.com'is returning 601. Please check your url and try again."

Here my file:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appIDs": [
                "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
                "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
                "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
                "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
                "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
                "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID"
            ],
            "components": [
                {
                    "/": "/myapp-app",
                    "comment": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "appID": "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
            "paths": [
                "/myapp-app"
            ]
        },
        {
            "appID": "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
            "paths": [
                "/myapp-app"
            ]
        },
        {
            "appID": "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
            "paths": [
                "/myapp-app"
            ]
        },
        {
            "appID": "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
            "paths": [
                "/myapp-app"
            ]
        },
        {
            "appID": "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
            "paths": [
                "/myapp-app"
            ]
        },
        {
            "appID": "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID",
            "paths": [
                "/myapp-app"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I cannot find an issue in my file. There are 6 appIds because we had 6 environments for our app. What I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52186038/921573

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/anhar/6d50c023f442fb2437e1) tutorial may help you.

Comment: @omerfarukozturk thank you, I've used it for configuration universal links

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help someone... I've added this part

`{ "appIDs": [ "App ID Prefix.Bundle ID", "..." ], "components": [ { "/": "/myapp-app", "comment": "" } ] },`

to support iOS 13. I've removed this part and universal links works for me know even on iOS 13.