# Universal Link fails in iOS 13

Tags: ios-universal-links

When the user comes from anywhere to my url, the application is supposed to open the app by using Universal Links. This feature works fine with iOS 14, but not with iOS 13 and 12.
This is my association file.

```
{
  "applinks": {
     "apps": [],
     "details": [
        {
           "appID": "1234.com.mycompany.myapp",
           "paths": [
              "/222/Auth/*"
           ]
      }
     ]
  }
}
```

What's even funnier, is that Safari recognises that the URL is a universal link.
[image: universal link]

What's going on? Why Universal link behaves differently on iOS 14?

Comment: well I'm struggling too with the AASA. My file has the same format as your's even if I have two app ids. I made the error of adding the .json extension so the application can not now download the file. We have to deploy a new file to the server. While searching, I found that Apple has changed the file format https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains I found this information from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186038/app-search-api-validation-tool-displays-example-com-is-returning-469-please-ch/63894613#63894613

Comment: Now I'm a little bit confused due to your screenshot. I don't know if i have to switch to the new format or keep it as you have done.